# How to Extract the output from line in flask

Tags: python, flask

i have the following code :

```
def sub():
    request_body = request.form['name']
    process = subprocess.Popen("./first.sh" + ' ' + request_body,stdout=PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    isexecuted=False
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
        print (line)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    
    if 'Code Execution Completed' in str(line):
        isexecuted = True
        print ('Process Completed Successfully')
        return ('Ok Json files are generated ')
```

basically what i want to achieve is that after the code runs i want to return a response, i am running a subprocess of python file and in that python file there is a string which print 'code execution Completed' . i have tried to take as when iterator finds 'code execution completed'  then it can return a response but unfortunately i am getting errors can anyone help .

Comment: Putting raw user input in the command with `shell=True` seems like a massive security hole in waiting...

Comment: for learning purposes . how can i find that particular string of 'Code execution completed ' ? can you please let me know thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and found that the items(`line`) in your iterable are bytes objects.

You need to decode the bytes object to a string as your last line is in string. So the updated `if` condition is

```
if 'Code Execution Completed' in line.decode("utf-8"):
```

or

```
if 'Code Execution Completed' in str(line, "utf-8"):
```

Comment: Thank you i have tried and it literally worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Rather than look for a specific string, I would look at the **return code** for your shell script. It should be 0 in case of success and something else in case of problems.

Check the value of `process.returncode` when your call terminates. [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

And maybe you should explicitly address the alternative outcome too. If an error occurs, log it and make sure it is brought to your attention.